# C# 2D pointer array

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers

I am currently messing around with C# in order to be able to approach ASP.NET with an acceptable knowledge base. In order to do so I occasionally look at my old C++ code and see if I can figure out how to make it work in C#.

So I figured that I will look into arrays, a pretty common way to store data. What I was wondering is what would the C# equivalent of creating a two dimensional array via pointers would look like?

I know that in C++ one way to do it could look like this:

```
double **myArray; 

myArray = new double * [rows];

for(int I = 0; I < rows; I++) {
myArray[I] = new double[cols];
}
```

I also know that in C# you could easily just say double [rows,cols] and that would create a 2D array. I know that C++ and C# most likely treat pointers differently, but just for the sake of interest, how would I mimic a similar behavior in C#?

Cheers.

Comment: The rule of thumb in C# is to never use pointers unless you have a very good reason for doing so. What is it you are trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Not sure why the -1, oh well. Trying to accomplish really nothing aside from furthering my knowledge. Knowledge for knowledge sake. On occasion I like to try to convert my old C++, or at least try, into C# code. So I was wondering if that were possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# arrays and C++ pointers are incredibly similar, with the biggest difference is that C# has a layer of managed logic on top of the array data.

An array of pointers in C# is possible. You could do it, for example, with:

```
unsafe
{
    double*[] ptrArray = new double*[5];
    ptrArray[2][0] = 4.0;

    double*[,] ptr2DArray = new double*[5,5];
    ptr2DArray [2, 2][0] = 4.0;
}
```

However, like I said in my previous comment, using pointers in C# is discouraged, and generally you want to use a managed approach whenever possible. Personally, I cannot fathom a need for creating an array of pointers (much less a 2D array) and I imagine that if someone's program needs a structure like this, then they probably need to rethink their approach.

Comment: gotcha, ty for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Usually pointers are very less used in C#, When you use pointers in C# it is considered as unsafe context.

Please check following [MSDN Pointer Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx) that illustrates how to use pointers.

I would like to say don't use pointers if not required. You can use [Ref Keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) and [Out keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) to pass your parameter as a reference.

When you use pointer you loose all managed code benefits.

You can check [C# ref is it like a pointer in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207455/c-sharp-ref-is-it-like-a-pointer-in-c-c-or-a-reference-in-c).

Apart from that i think that all arrays are already Reference Type even if it contains all members of value type.

Check [Value Types and Reference Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) in C#.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a significant difference between & and ref when passing items by reference?

Comment: @SomeStudent There are some subtle differences that have to do with how types and objects are handled and passed around in the CLR, but in practice, not really.