# Are there any big differences between pointers in c and c++?

Tags: pointers

I am studying c++, and I want to get a deeper understanding of pointers. There is an Oreilly book called "Understanding and using pointers in C". Is this a good reference, or will  it likely teach outdated techniques? It looks like a very good read.

Comment: I think this has been posted before? Have a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146202/difference-between-pointer-in-c-and-reference-type-in-c-sharp

Comment: I think the OP is asking about C and C++ pointers, not C++ pointers and C# reference types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no differences. You can take any c/c++ book of the past 30 years and you will read the same about pointers and their concepts. But instead of bying a book I would recommend just to read this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert at either language but there shouldn't be much of a difference. 
Generally, pointers are basically variables that point to the address of another variable. As for the syntax between the two languages, there's not really a major difference since C++ basically comes from C.