# Class and List<> Reference Type in c#

Tags: c#, list, class, reference-type

I have some doubts in below code regarding CASE 1 and CASE 2,

In CASE-1, we are assigning `obj1=null`, but in obj2 the copied value is still present as i =10.
In CASE-2, we do something in `List`, but the value changed in one list is affecting the value in another `List`.

What is the logic behind this as both are reference types.

**CASE- 1**

```
Class A    
{
public int i;
}

A obj1 = new A();
obj1.i =10;

A obj2 = obj1;
obj1 = null;
```

**CASE- 2**

```
List<int> test1 = new List<int>();
test1.Add(101);

List<int> test2 = test1;
test1.Add(201);
```

Comment: For reference types - simple rule, you get *one* object each time you call `new`. So in both cases, you only have one *object*, no matter how many *references* to that object you may have created.

Answer (score 3):

the logic is simple in both:

both `A obj2` and `List<int> test2` are reference to the same type as `A obj1` and `List<int> test1`

whhich means that when you perform:

```
Class A    
{
public int i;
}

A obj1 = new A();
obj1.i =10;

A obj2 = obj1;
obj1 = null;
```

The value of `obj2` will be assigned with the value of `obj1` but is a object of it's own, it did not become `obj1` but rather, just referenced him. `obj2` became a new object of type `A` with the values assigned in `obj1`.

When you assign `obj1=null` then `obj2` will not be affected as it's value is already assigned.

however if you change it to:

```
obj1 = null;
A obj2 = obj1;
```

then `obj2` will be null, as `obj2` is now referencing an empty object.

the same applied in case 2:

`List<int> test2` is referencing `List<int> test1` and will be assigned it's value.
as a result this piece of code:

```
List<int> test1 = new List<int>();
test1.Add(101);

List<int> test2 = test1;
test1.Add(201);
```

will produce the following items in test2:

```
101
201
```

you can read further into reference types in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) at Microsoft docs. It is pretty extended and covers almost everything.

Answer (score 2):

1. When you use new keyword at that time some memory is going to allocate and depending on type reference type and value type it get allocation in Heap or may be Stack. ( It is possible that value type may assigned to heap and it entirely depends on CLR)
2. Difference between reference type and value type is that reference type hold reference of ( Address of) particular object created in heap. In value type , variable it self hold value.
3. Now in your case 1 
   A a=  new A(); // At this time memory allocated and that allocated memory location address is being assigned to variable a.

   A a1 = a; // At this point new variable a1 is created and that point to same address location in heap as variable a.

   a = null; // At this point variable a is set to null means it links with actual object allocated is heap get removed.

   but a1 still hold the reference so it can access value
4. In case 2 ( This is also case of reference type)
   // Your variable test1 and test2 are different but holding same location of address from heap.

   // so if you change any item it get affected both variable as both point to same location.

   // Now if you do test1 = null then also test2 to do same thing but you can not access by test1 as it  is null now.

Comment: Focussing on heap/stack is [irrelevant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/) for most purpooses.

Comment: "depending on type reference type and value type it get allocation in Heap or Stack" - No, that's not true.

Comment: a "reference" is not an "address".

Comment: A reference doesn't have to be to the heap.

Comment: "In value type , variable it self hold value." - no, not true.

Comment: "At this time memory allocated" - not necessarily.

Comment: "with memory location removed" - you're a bit vague on this one, but assigning `null` does nothing to me memory.

Comment: null doesn't mean the heap allocation is removed, the heap allocation is removed when either collected by the garbage collector or by implementing the Idisposable(); on the object.

Comment: I do respect everyone comments but to this question I did not feel that I have to go to the details levels of CLR working , C# compiler optimization of code and how garbage collector works for C# and how it works in server machine or client machine, How it works in debug and release mode of code. I try to give answer which clarify its confusion of why ?

Comment: @BarrJ - It's only the first way. Implementing `IDisposable` (or calling `.Dispose()`) does not remove it from the heap (or memory).

Comment: I didn't say it does, I said that it's a way of disposing the object.

Comment: you cannot control garbage collector's work after all.

Answer (score 0):

#### CASE-1

```
obj1 = null;
```

reference to the object from `obj1` has been removed. The object still exists thanks to `obj2`.

#### CASE-2

Instead

```
test1 = null;
```

the method on `List<int>` is performed:

```
test1.Add(201);
```

Both `test1` and `test2` still point to the same `List<int>`, so changes in the list are visible.

Comment: This is totally wrong. obj1 is alive until being disposed or collected by garbage collector, obj2 is an independed object not connected to obj1! assigning null does not remove the object. test1 and test 2 does not point to the same list! they reference the same value, this is different. the lists are different lists!

Comment: what you just said right now is, if I add another item to list1, then the item will be added to list2 just the same, this is wrong just as thinking that assigning to null does the garbage collector's job of disposing the object.

Comment: @BarrJ First comment: I did not write that `obj1` will be disposed or collected, only that it stops pointing to the same object - instance of the `A` class. │ Second comment: Adding items to the list `test1` or `test2` will be visible through both variables.

Comment: This is your exact mistake, it does not 'point', it is referencing! this is a different thing. It does not REFERENCE the instance. same with the list. the value in list2 is REFERENCING list1. it is a new list altogether. if you add items to list2, it will not be reflected in list1!

Comment: please look at this link to see differences between reference and a pointer in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430112/what-is-the-difference-between-a-c-sharp-reference-and-a-pointer

Comment: if the object would have POINTED, the new instance code would have been test1* = null. THIS IS POINTING TO NULL.

Comment: I know there is difference between the reference and the pointer, but the terminology confuses you. Please check with the debugger if you're right.

Comment: I admit my confusion regarding the lists :) thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think Barr J's answer is a good one, and I'm not sure whether you'll find mine more or less helpful, but this stuff can be confusing enough that I think it's worthwhile to try explaining what's going on in a slightly different way.

```
A obj1 = new A();  // 1.1
obj1.i = 10;       // 1.2

A obj2 = obj1;     // 1.3
obj1 = null;       // 1.4
```

On line 1.1, the `new` operator creates an instance of a reference type `A`, and the `=` operator stores a reference to that instance in a variable called `obj1`. In order to understand what's going on with your code it's important to distinguish between the *reference* (the value stored in `obj1`) and the *referent* (the object to which that value refers, which is stored elsewhere).

On line 1.2, the `.` operator serves to *dereference* the reference stored in `obj1`—in other words, to access its referent, the instance of `A` that you created on line 1.1. This allows you to access the field `i` of that instance and assign it a value of 10.

Line 1.3 copies the reference stored in `obj1` into a second variable called `obj2`. You now have two references with the same referent. This means that `obj2.i` is also equal to 10, because the expressions `obj1.i` and `obj2.i` refer to exactly the same value.

Line 1.4 stores the null-reference into `obj1`. The crucial difference between lines 1.2 and 1.4 is that there is no dereferencing occurring on line 1.4, so you're not affecting the referent in any way. All you're doing is replacing a reference to an object with a reference to nothing.

Now consider the code from your second example:

```
List<int> test1 = new List<int>();  // 2.1
test1.Add(101);                     // 2.2

List<int> test2 = test1;            // 2.3
test1.Add(201);                     // 2.4
```

Lines 2.1–2.3 are analogous to their counterparts in the first example: they construct an instance of `List<int>` and two references to that instance, which are stored in two variables of type `List<T>` called `test1` and `test2`. But line 2.4 is different: whereas line 1.4 replaced one reference with another, line 2.4 uses the `.` operator again to access the referent of `test1` and update its contents.

You'll see the value 201 in the list regardless of whether you access it by way of the reference stored in `test1` or the reference stored in `test2` because both references have the same referent; in other words, you have only created a single list.

Answer (score 0):

`obj1` and `test1` both are variables of reference type, just like **pointers**. They store **references** to their data (objects). `obj1` and `obj2` reference the same object but they are different variables. So that you assign null to `obj1` doesn't change the data (object). `test1` and `test2` are different variables too, but `test1.Add` and `test2.Add` call the same method of the same object that they both reference.